# There is a thread with negligible linear density and cross-sectional area on a frictionless pulley

Tags: forces

If you hang weights on both sides and release both hands at the same time in a static and taut state, is the tension at each point of the thread at the top of the pulley guaranteed to be constant throughout the movement?

Comment: Is the pulley movable or fixed?

Answer (score 0):

> Is the tension at each point of the thread at the top of the pulley guaranteed to be constant throughout the movement?

Yes, as long as the pulley is smooth and the thread has negligible mass and the masses on each end of the thread are constant and there are no variable forces such as drag forces involved.

Comment: how can you show that? It would be nice to be able to view it mathematically, including the approximation process.

Comment: @python Since the thread has negligible mass the forces on each element of it must net to zero. Since there is no friction the only forces on each element of the thread are the tensions on each side of it. Therefore the tension in the thread must be uniform along its length. As long as the masses on each end of the thread are constant and there are no drag forces or other forces that vary with time, then the tension in the thread will also be constant.

Comment: First of all, what happens to gravity and normal force?

Comment: @python The thread has negligible mass so it also has negligible weight.